# Get stored index from object literal in angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular

I have a stored object literal which returns 2 or more objects depending on the users actions. This is then filtered further depending on if they are complete or not, so there are generally 2 object arrays that are sent to the view.

in the view i do a simple `ngFor`

```
 <ion-card *ngFor="let item of inProgressList">
    ...
```

Which is a segment of the complete list held in a variable `programsList`

In order to change an item from `in progress` to `complete` i need to update the object, which works fine, however i cannot correctly pass the index.

```
filledOutFormsData[this.index].complete = true;
```

As i cannot get the correct index based on the array that has been filtered.

I cannot use

```
  <ion-card *ngFor="let item of inProgressList; let i = index">
```

Because that will return a index of the looped items which will be incorrect once one other object is equal to `complete`

Basically i need to get the object key from the original object literal into the filtered array to use in the view so that i can pass the index.

Answer (score 0):

So i got this working by adding a custom pipe which filters the `programsList` instead of passing in two separate lists, I can then use the `trackBy` option to pass the correct index.